# Why in Python, += and -= are considered as delimiters?

Tags: python, operators, delimiter

I am reading a [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/lang/python/lexicalstructure/) about python, it's lexical structure to be more precise.
And I just want to know why in Python, the:

```
+= , -= ,  *= ,  /= ,  //= ,  %=, <= ,  |= ,  ^= , >>= , <<=  , **=
```

are considered as delimiters and not operators? After all, the "+=" is an increment operator, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "delimiters"?

Comment: Source? Hard to explain choice of vocabulary when you don't provide your source.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense actually.

Comment: "Delimiters" are mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#delimiters) in the language reference.

Comment: In a language grammar you have syntax like <expr> := <expr> <opr> <expr>. It is how the interpreter goes through and tokenizes the lines of code. I'm guessing it is called a delimiter, because it can separate expressions. Like what FlexKling said in the lexical analysis for the compiler/interpreter.

Comment: You don't need whitespace around tokens that are also delimiters. That's all.

Comment: I deleted my comment since I'm not sure about it. As can bee seen in Kevin's link, there is also a section "Operators". I guess one has to distinguish between parsing and runtime semantics. It seems that `=` is not considered to be an operator in Python, and hence `+=` can't really be an operator itself.

Comment: But what you said made some sense to me actually.

Comment: It doesn't make it right though ;) I let the language exports speak for themselves ;)

Comment: @JustinEngel You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax you refer to are used in [augmented assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements). Like regular [assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), these are not expressions, so they are *not operators either*.

They happen to *closely resemble* certain arithmetic operators, but only in that they fall back to using those operators if the assignment target does not implement a [specific augmented assignment special method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) for the operation.

Delimiters are tokens that do not require whitespace around them in source code, which is why those tokens are listed in that list.

Comment: That is exactly the documentation link I was looking for, +1.

Comment: So even if they perform some function, they are not considered as operators or expressions?

Comment: @the-sizixe: Exactly. They cannot be used as part of a larger expression, which operators *can* be used for.